# How to make timeago.js show only hours ago

Tags: javascript, jquery, timeago

I am using timeago.js to show the date. However, I want to show the "hours ago" feature of the plugin if a particular date is less than 2 days. If a date is more than 2 days, it'll show the usual "3 days ago".

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Just note - this plugin has a bug for future time/date. (returns time AGO for future)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, I have to modify the plugin. Have to set the "hours" to be less than 48 hours.

```
 var words = seconds < 45 && substitute($l.seconds, Math.round(seconds)) ||
 hours < 48 && substitute($l.hours, Math.round(hours)) ||
```

Comment: The plugin does not have any settings for that neither provides any object to manipulate with - so this is probably the best plugin-like solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You can of course modify plugin like you did, or you could run the dates over again and check whether they are more than two days or not - if they are - just rewrite the string to hours, something like this:

```
$(function(){
    var oneHour = 1*60*60*1000; // one hour in miliseconds
    var twoDays = 2*24*oneHour; // two days in miliseconds

    $('.timeAgoSelector').each(function(){
        $t = $(this);
        var agoDate = new Date( $t.attr('title') ).getTime()
        var currDate = new Date().getTime();
        var timeAgo = currDate - agoDate;
        if( (timeAgo < twoDays) && (timeAgo >= oneHour) ){
            var hours = ((timeAgo/1000)/60)/60;
            hours = Math.floor(hours);
            if( hours < 2 ) $t.html( 'an hour ago' );
                else $t.html( hours + ' hours ago' );
        } //else => do nothing (keep original content)
    });

});
```

=> http://jsfiddle.net/chgvcudL/

Answer (score 0):

I think [timeago.js](https://github.com/hustcc/timeago.js) can help you, and the tiny library is supported by me.

You can just customize you locale function for your need.

```
const yourLocale = (number, index, totalSec) => {
   // format totalSec into hours.
   const hours = getHours(totalSec);
   return hours +' hours ago';
};
```

Then `register` it.

```
timeago.register('yourLocale', yourLocale);
```

Them `format` use it.

```
timeago.format(time, 'yourLocale');
```

done!